# How to center row correctly

Tags: flutter

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19azB.jpg)

I've got a Row with 'Long Text', divider and 'Text'. How can i align them properly, so the divider would always be at center of the screen (I added a red rectangle to ease positiong of the divider relative to the center). Also, the content of 'Text', so it could occupy more or less space. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 100),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Long text",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              Container(height: 16, width: 1, color: Colors.orange),
              SizedBox(
                width: 12,
              ),
              Text(
                "Text",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Center(child: Container(color: Colors.red, width: 3, height: 20))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your texts with `Expanded` and then with `Center`.
I tried this snippet locally and it works as described:

```
Row(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
 children: <Widget>[
  Expanded(
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "Long text",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          fontSize: 14,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  SizedBox(
    width: 12,
  ),
  Container(height: 16, width: 1, color: Colors.orange),
  SizedBox(
    width: 12,
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "Text",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 14,
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
       ),
      ),
     ),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]